# ProcessBuilder cannot return JSon String

Tags: java, json, child-process

i'm using ProcessBuilder to run a command.
The command output is in jSON format, and i want to return the String and then map it with my Models.

The problem is i get no result when trying to read the stream from the process.
The command I use also has a non jSON output. If I use this command version, I get the result, so the problem happens only when i want to read jSON..

```
public String getPlate(String image) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("alpr", "-c eu", "-j on", "-n 1", image);
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               builder.append(line);
               builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            String result = builder.toString();
            return result;
    }
```

Using this command, no result is given, if I use the non-jSON version

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("alpr", "-c eu", "-n 1", image);
```

I have the result..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your process is almost certainly blocking because its output isn't being read.  You don't start reading its output until it's finished, and it can't finish until its output is read, because your child process generates enough output to fill the pipe buffers between the parent and child process.  Since nothing is reading the pipe while the child is running, it blocks trying to write.

Your non-JSON output is probably smaller, so it doesn't fill up the pipe buffers in the process output stream, allowing the process to finish and then your parent Java process can read the data in the pipe buffers.

You need to change the order of what you're doing:

```
public String getPlate(String image) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        ProcessBuilder pb =
            new ProcessBuilder("alpr", "-c eu", "-j on", "-n 1", image);
        Process p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               builder.append(line);
               builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        // wait for the child process *after*
        // reading all its output
        p.waitFor();

        String result = builder.toString();
        return result;
}
```

That's a quick fix - it's actually not very robust.  If your child process also generates significant error output, that can block too.

You can use the [`redirectError()`, `redirectInput()`, and `redirectOutput()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectError%28java.io.File%29) methods as needed to prevent such blocking.